# How to install Estru3D - Structural Analysis Software?

Tags: apt, package-management, language-support

I had problems installing Estru3D. It requires Gambas3 to be installed as a prerequisite. But it doesn't work with the newest Gambas3 installed in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Workaround:

- Uninstall the newest version of Gambas3:

  `sudo apt-get remove --purge gambas3`
- Install Gdebi:

  `sudo apt-get install gdebi`
- Download these files:

  gambas3-gb-qt4_3.8.4-28.47-ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
  gambas3-gb-qt4-webkit_3.8.4-28.47-ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
  ([download](https://launchpad.net/%7Egambas-team/+archive/ubuntu/gambas3/+build/8748961))
- Install them by right-click on it and choose "Open with Gdebi".
- Install Estru3d by right-click on it and choose "Open with Gdebi".

On first run Estru3d might display an error message with some language files/folder missing. This happens if your Ubuntu interface uses other language than en or es. Just make a copy of the en folder (and all its' contents) and rename it with the language name of your Ubuntu (e.g. fr, ge, etc). And, of course, accept the GPL licence. This will make it start, but the interface language will still be es (spanish).
Any help with an english translation is most welcomed.